# Identify bytes corresponding to the transcription response in Google Cloud Transcription API

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api

While performing a live streaming recognition using google's ASR apis, we send byte arrays in real-time and receive tentative textual responses.

Is there a way to annotate each request corresponding to the bytes sent and receive an identifier of which text corresponds to what bytes in the response.

The use case is that I want to get an accurate handle on the latency of the transcription API.